# Determining surname for 1782 baptism in Breconshire, Wales?

Tags: surnames, wales, baptism-records, 1780s, breconshire

In [Finding birth/baptism/marriage record for Priscilla who married printer Henry Hughes probably about 1810 in Breconshire, Wales?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6611/finding-birth-baptism-marriage-record-for-priscilla-who-married-printer-henry-hu) I sought vital records for Priscilla Hughes, the printer, of Struet, Brecon, Wales.

I now suspect that Priscilla may have been Priscilla Thomas who was baptised on 11 May 1782 at Hay, Breconshire, Wales, to Thomas Howels and Susanna. This is based on her age of death being 57 in 1839, the county where she seems to have spent her known life being Breconshire (Brecon, Hay and Talgarth), and her relatively uncommon Christian name.

"Wales Births and Baptisms, 1541-1907," database, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FMMS-KWL : accessed 23 August 2015), Pricilla Thomas, 11 May 1782; citing HAY,BRECON,WALES, reference ; FHL microfilm 104,467.

I have not seen an image of this baptism and am wondering how to interpret her surname?  I am assuming that she was "Priscilla daughter of Thomas [Howels]" so would it be appropriate to record her as Priscilla Howels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am confident this is simply an error in indexing, and the surname should have been indexed as Howels.

This can be confirmed by looking at the index and images for this baptism register on [FindMyPast](http://search.findmypast.co.uk/results/world-records/powys-baptisms?firstname=priscilla&firstname_variants=true&lastname=howells).

You will also note that this Priscilla cannot be your ancestor because she is found in the [burials](http://search.findmypast.co.uk/results/world-records/powys-burials?firstname=priscilla&firstname_variants=true&lastname=howells) for the same parish in 1782.

Answer (score -2):

There may be two members of the Hughes family still living at '73 The Struet, Brecon' which may be the same house and family that you are asking about.

The title deeds of this house may answer your question and establish the family line.

Comment: I have found that address (73, The Struet) with a Hughes living there now (http://www.britishphonebook.com/search.php?last=HUGHES&city=BRECON), but http://www.breconremembers.co.uk/WW1_Brecon_U3A.pdf suggests a family named Bather lived there in 1911 and the 1939 Register has a family named Price.